# Unwanted flickering in rendered animation

Tags: rendering

I have made an aquarium with some youtube help then rendered to see if it's Ok (and it's not).

**My video to check:** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J6HydYXtbdk&feature=youtu.be

You can see on the video that it's flickering (like the bottom of the aquarium). I don't know why it's happening.

My render settings are FFMPEG VIDEO with 30 fps.

Comment: Welcome to BSE.  Could you please confirm which version of blender you are using and in particular which render engine. The `blender-render` tag implies the usage of the blender internal render engine no longer available in 2.8.  Possibly related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48342/what-causes-rendered-frame-flickering   https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21666/video-editing-encodeing-rendering-video-always-flickers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A slight modification of Laurent Roro's solution worked for me. I changed camera Clip End first, but the flickering remained the same. I then changed camera Clip Start, and the flickering completely disappeared. My scene had objects from a little over 100 feet from the camera to 7 miles back, so the default (?) setting of just over zero for Clip Start apparently caused a lot of flickering on the distant objects.

Update: In reply to Ben's inquiry, while I don't have the scene in front of me right now for exact numeric values, I lowered the Clip End to a little beyond the farthest object. Like I said, that didn't really change anything for me. I just now opened Blender on my work machine, and I see that the camera defaults to a Clip Start of .328 feet. I'm guessing the reason mine started out far lower might be a result of importing the camera from After Effects. Anyhow, I changed Clip Start to 100 feet, since the nearest object was at 140 feet or so (can't recall). My reasoning was that it might be similar to the old shadow maps in Blender internal, but that's not a very scientific line of reasoning, or an explanation. Anyhow, the difference was dramatic. I had a particular, low roughness tower in the background that had been flickering like crazy, such that the entire tower basically changed shades of gray from frame to frame.

Comment: Would be useful (though not essential) to know whether you needed to increase or decrease each value, and since you've given some numeric values for your scene, it might also be helpful to know what numeric values you used for that scene that made it work.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually fix in eevee : in camera setting, change "clip end" to a lower value.

This has absolutely nothing to do with lighting, you can look for z-fighting.

Comment: Hello, can you give as more info how lower "clip end" affects this flickering in render or how it solves z-fighting? Thank you

Comment: Adjusting clip start and end in camera settings worked to fix my flickering issues. No need to switch to Cycles! Thank you!

Comment: Me too. I had to change both the start and end. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using Blender 2.80+. This is *most likely* caused by either the lighting, or the fact that you are using EEVEE to render. Now EEVEE is not bad, but there are some settings it uses that produce this kind of look if not adjusted. I would recommend that You use *Cycles* to render. Settings to change the renderer are in the render tab in the properties section. Now changing the materials to different colors and shaders *should* fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like Evee render..
Would say please try adjust and tweak your lights and the shadow Parameter  but
It looks like lightbleeading in Evee or shadow flickering .
you can try to use Lightprobe and  refletiv maps  they are special designed for Evee for a stabil and better lock .
But the rendertime increases massiv 
Have a look here 
How do the new light probes in Eevee work?
[How do the new light probes in Eevee work?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/128162/how-do-the-new-light-probes-in-eevee-work/128164#128164)
Another User try to use and explore 
Evee again ...

Answer (score 0):

Increasing the number of samples to 256 in Volumetric setting in Eevee render tab helped me to get rid of the flickering.

Answer (score 0):

try changing this Clip Start option in View tab of Tools menu -

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had an object parented to a active rigid body physics object and this child object was strobing on and off while rendering in cycles. None of these solutions worked but I finally figured out that the child object had a rigid body modifier left over from a previous approach. There was a warning under the physics tab that alerted me that this was illegal (see pic) and as soon as I deleted the physics from the child object everything rendered fine.[image: This was the error message that marked my problem with strobing]